# Linear algebra - Apply inverted function to another function given by a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, polynomials, vector-spaces

Given the vector space: $\ V:= [~~f:ℝ→ℝ∣ for ~~ a_0,…,a_4~∈~ℝ~and~ f(x)=∑^4_{i=0}a_ix^i ~~\forall ~x∈ℝ]$

and given the function:

$\ φ: V \rightarrow V, ~defined~ as~~ φ(f)(x)=f″(x)+x⋅f′(x)−f(x+1) $

How do I apply the inverted function $\ φ^{-1}$({g}) to the given function g ∈ V, where g is defined as $\ g(x)=3x^ 4+2x^3−x+1? $

Comment: You are asked to solve $3x^4+2x^3-x+1=f^{"}(x)+xf^{'}(x)-f(x+1)$ for $f$ where $f$ is also in $V$. Do you see how to proceed then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f\in V$ be defined by the scalars $a_0,\ldots ,a_4$. Then

$$\phi (f)(x)=-a_0-a_1+a_2-a_3-a_4+(-2a_2+3a_3-4a_4)x+(a_2-3a_3+6a_4)x^2+(2a_3-4a_4)x^3+3a_4x^4$$

for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ (this is direct computation: expand everything then gather it together).

Thus, we have $f\in \phi ^{-1}(\{ g\} )$ if and only if the following system of equations is satisfied:

$$\begin{cases} -a_0-a_1+a_2-a_3-a_4=1 \\ -2a_2+3a_3-4a_4=-1 \\ a_2-3a_3+6a_4=0 \\  2a_3-4a_4=2 \\ 3a_4=3 \end{cases} $$

Now, I let you solve this by yourself.